# Wrong encoding in letter_opener preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, encoding, devise

I'm using `letter_opener` gem for previewing sending out emails.

The default `Devise` and an application locale is `ru` (Russian, https://github.com/kiote/devise-rus/blob/master/devise.ru.yml).

I have a problem with email encoding: [image]

Does anybody have the same issue? I have been checked the locale file encoding, and it seems to be ok.